# Create Model field based on existing models

Tags: django, django-models

I am currently working to implement review app in Django. 
In models.py of this review app:

```
from salon.models import salon
from services.models import Service
from packages.models import Packages

    MODEL_OBJECTS = (
    ('salon':salon),
    ('service':Service),
    ('package':Packages),
)
class Reviews(models.MODEL):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name=_("user"), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    comment = models.TextField(_("User Comment"))
    rating = models.IntegerRangeField(min_value=1, max_value=5, blank=True)
    rate_object = models.CharField(_("Model Choice") choices=MODEL_OBJECTS,default='salon')
    rate_object_id = models.IntegerField(_("rate_object_id"))
```

I want **rate_object** to contain model for which the rating is being done and **rate_object_id** to contain the instance id of the model selected in **rate_object**.

I am not able to think forward on implementing this.

Comment: You don't need to do this yourself, Django already has you covered: [generic relations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations).

Comment: thanks @DanielRoseman i am working toward this direction.